# Good resources for visualizing time-to-event(s) data where event is a continuous variable

Tags: data-visualization, time-varying-covariate, kaplan-meier

I am analyzing patients' rehabilitation use over a 5-year period. Describing their rehabilitation is challenging since:

1. I should describe the proportion excluded from rehabilitation (zero-inflatation)
2. I should describe amount (hours) received by receivers
3. Time-to-event analysis needed since rehabilitation's start may delay for a subproportion
4. Time-to-event analysis needed since rehabilitation may be short-living for a subproportion, meaning that I should also analyze its end (duration of rehabilitation)

**Do you have good suggestions for visualizing such data?** Kaplan-Meier curves with cumulative rehabilitation amount received? Any good resources for visualizing such data?

Comment: This R package might be good. [survminer](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/survminer/vignettes/Informative_Survival_Plots.html)

Comment: Need to distinguish visualization of summary measures vs. raw data.  For the latter see http://hbiostat.org/rflow/descript.html

Comment: Good point. I need to visualize summary data only as I have way too many to show individual-level estimates.

Comment: You are listing 4 different variables. What is your actual outcome? What is it you want the plot(s) to show? If you want to visualize 4 different things, you should probably use (at least) 4 different plots, not 1.  Can you provide an example dataset for people to work with?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if it is what you are looking for, but if you are trying to visualize the effect of a continuous variable on a time-to-event outcome you may be interested in the `contsurvplot` R-package https://robindenz1.github.io/contsurvplot/